# Left join rows and right table rows in same column

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables (Manager and Worker). I want to do a left join from Manager to Worker. The name of  workers under a manager should come below manager name. The expected output is presented below:-

```
Manager Table:

ManagerCode   Name  Age
1             Chris  52
2             Rick   55
3             David  50


Worker Table

ManagerCode   WName Age
1             Harry  33
1             Phil   40
2             Johnny 28
2             Jeff   47

Expected table:

ManagerCode   Name    Age
1            Chris
1            Harry
1            Phil
2            Rick
2            Johnny
2            Jeff
3            David
```

Left join results both manager and worker names side by side. But I want them in one column.

Comment: I suppose you want preserve ManagerCode? So it will be [1,1,1,2,2,2] in final result, right? Or you want to renumber rows?

Comment: @AlexYu yes, it will be [1,1,1,2,2,2]. Also there are some extra columns in Worker table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meed `UNION ALL` and not a join:

```
select t.managercode, t.name, t.age
from (
select managercode, name, age, 1 as ismanager from Manager
union all
select managercode, wname, age, 0 from Worker
) t
order by t.managercode, t.ismanager desc
```

The column `ismanager` is used to sort the manager before all the workers under them.
 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7wriXVgLhDo4BFsCCDe9F/0).
Results:

```
| managercode | name   | age |
| ----------- | ------ | --- |
| 1           | Chris  | 52  |
| 1           | Phil   | 40  |
| 1           | Harry  | 33  |
| 2           | Rick   | 55  |
| 2           | Johnny | 28  |
| 2           | Jeff   | 47  |
```

Comment: If some columns in manager and worker are different, then will union all work? I have not included all the columns

Comment: Include in the unioned queries only the common columns or add dummy null columns so they have the same number of columns.

Comment: I need to include more columns from Manager table. Say office location. Then this location should show for workers also. Or shall I use a left join as a manger might not have workers under him.

Comment: This query returns the expected results that you posted in your question. If you have a different requirement you can post a new question.